# Java random with different behaviour in 2 places

Tags: java, random

I've got tired of searching on Google without finding a solution so...

This is the relevant code:

```
public class Main {

  public char source[] = { 'd', 'o', 'i', 't', 'r', 'e', 'c', 'n', 'x', 'y' }; 

  //...
  // I don't have a given seed, which is the right approach, 
  //   from what I've read until now
  Random rand = new Random(); 
  //...
  public void init() {
      char config[] = new char[10];

      int life= 0;
      int pos;
      for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
              do {
                  pos = rand.nextInt(10);
              } while (source[pos] == '?');
              config[i] = source[pos];
              source[pos] = '?';
          }
          life= rand.nextInt((30 + 1) -1);
          population[j] = new Individual(config, 0, life);
          //...
      }
  }
  //...
}
```

When I call `init` in the `main()` method, I get the same sequence for all the individuals from the population, **but** different numbers for the life. I tried to create `rand` inside the `init()` method, to send it as a parameter from `main()`, nothing worked.

My question is: how can I generate really random sequences for the population?

Individual:

```
public class Individual {
    private char config[];
    private int age;
    private int life;

    //default constr

    public Individ(char config[], int age, int life) {
      this.config= config;
      this.age= age;
      this.life= life;
    }

    //getters, setters
}
```

main():

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Main main = new Main();
      main.init();
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
          System.out.print(main.population[i].getConfig()[j] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println(main.population[i].getAge() + " " + main.populatie[i].getLife());
      }
}
```

Output:

```
...
e o x c i r y t d n 0 15
e o x c i r y t d n 0 25
e o x c i r y t d n 0 12
e o x c i r y t d n 0 22
e o x c i r y t d n 0 15
...
```

Comment: no... Java Application

Comment: Where's `source` array declared and initialized?

Comment: `dasblinkenlight` nailed it. You've got the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not your number generator, it is the `config` array that you pass to all individuals. Arrays are reference objects, so when you change `config` in the loop to prepare it for the next individual, the changes become visible in all instances of `Individual` that you created before.

You need to either make a copy of `config` in the `Individual`'s constructor, or use a new array in each iteration of your `for` loop:

```
int life= 0;
int pos;
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    char config[] = new char[10]; // <<== Move the declaration here
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        do {
            pos = rand.nextInt(10);
        } while (source[pos] == '?');
        config[i] = source[pos];
        source[pos] = '?';
    }
    life= rand.nextInt((30 + 1) -1);
    population[j] = new Individual(config, 0, life);
}
```

Now each `Individual` gets his own copy of `config`, ensuring that each individual is different.

Comment: oohhhh... so that was the problem... and I was focused only on `Random`... thank you!